# html5 audio tag mp3 playback issues on FF and IE

Tags: html, firefox, audio, mp3, explorer

I recently realized that some mp3 files causes the "seeker" slider of an HTML5 audio control to fail on Firefox and Explorer.

Specifically, I can move the slider to the desired position, but the sound jumps to an incorrect time. Therefore, when the slider comes to the end, the song is already playing, and the current time keeps incrementing.

In addition, the track length (it's supposed to be a fixed value, loaded from the metadata) has a strange behavior given that point: it starts incrementing as the current time...

I found no differences between the files that work correctly and the files that don't (Not even in the codecs), but I suspect is a browser support related issue, since I didn't experience that problem using Chrome.

Just in case, you can download the file here:
http://www.4shared.com/mp3/JzSPjx3Qba/Quartet_12_Mov_1.html

And this is the test code I'm using:

```
<html>
<head>
   <title>Test Page</title>
</head>

<body>

<audio controls="controls" id="player">
    <source src="Beethoven - String Quartets/Quartet 12 Mov 1.mp3">
</audio>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks!

Comment: I can't download the file without sharing social network login data with a possibly shady file sharing site, so I can't verify the problem. However, I have seen HTML5 audio length issues involving MP3 files with hefty metadata chunks. See this question (and my answer) to see if that gives you some clues: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20711488/475067

Comment: @MultimediaMike sorry about the inconvenience. Please try this link, it shouldn't require any login:
[link](https://mega.co.nz/#!MZVT3aCL!PFwcNc8ir6MA74MfXkw5Q_m2L3lFZ3XVao9h9atRdCw)

Comment: By the way, I reviewed the question and your answer. It was helpful, but is definitely a different problem. I had no troubles on determining the correct duration for this mp3, the issue is on the playback, and seems to be browser-related.

Thanks, I much appreciate your help!