# HTML5 audio duration different between chrome safari and firefox

Tags: html, google-chrome, audio, safari, duration

I have some issue to understand why I have a difference between safari/firefox and chrome on the audio length of my mp3.

I'm recording 3600s mp3 file from shoutcast stream using cvlc. When I load the audio file into safari or firefox, I get 59:59 as duration, but when I load it into chrome, I get 59:52, but at 59:52 we are at the end of the file...

I can't find why ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML5 Audio Tag Showing Wrong Duration of MP3 in Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20711488/html5-audio-tag-showing-wrong-duration-of-mp3-in-chrome)

Comment: actually I checked this solution but it's not working ... that's why I think it might not be the same issue ...

Comment: I'm seeing a similar problem, though the duration difference is a lot greater (3.9 sec on FF vs 7.8 sec on Chrome). Thinking it might be a chrome bug, but unsure yet.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a Chrome bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=634262

If you follow the link, the commenters claim that it's been fixed in 54.0.2810.2. The latest stable version is 53.0.2785.116 (released 14th Sept 2016) so the fix is not available for the mainstream Chrome user.