# MediaPlayer miscalculates audio duration. getCurrentPosition() goes back when audio reaches the end

Tags: android, audio, ffmpeg, android-mediaplayer

I'm streaming .ogg files from my server.  The `MediaPlayer` plays the song to completion, but when it reaches the end of the song, `getCurrentPosition()` returns a time less than the actual duration of the song.  For 1 song it's only off by a second, but for another song it's off by 13 seconds.

I have a `SeekBar` that's updated every second by calling `getCurrentPosition()`, and once the bar reaches the end, it actually jumps back a few seconds.  And I can no longer use `seekTo()` into the segment of the song that's past the miscalculated duration because I receive the error: `Attempt to seek to past end of file`.

Chrome's html video element simply displays the songs with the incorrect durations.

Other tools like ffmpeg or this app on Windows 10 called PowerMediaPlayer both calculate the songs' durations perfectly.

I believe this problem is related to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20711488/html5-audio-tag-showing-wrong-duration-of-mp3-in-chrome), but the solution assumes ffmpeg also miscalculates the duration, which is not the case here. Using the `-vn` flag when converting audio files to ogg didn't change anything.

What are my options? Is there a way to get the MediaPlayer to calculate the correct duration?

**Update:**

Converting to mp3 has no issues (although I used `audioBitrate('96k')`instead of `audioQuality(2)`, but I require a solution to get ogg files working. Below is how I'm using ffmpeg to perform the conversion.  Another thing worth noting is that when I used `'vorbis'` instead of `'libvorbis'` for the codec the durations were off by less than a second, if at all.  However, I must use `'libvorbis'` because `'vorbis'` is experimental and results in significanlty inconsistent bitrates across different files given the same audio quality parameter. (And it ignores `audioBitrate()` entirely.)

```
ffmpeg( filepath )
    .toFormat( 'ogg' )
    .audioCodec( 'libvorbis' )
    .audioQuality( 2 )
    .output( destination )
    .run();
```

Comment: Did you resolve this issue?

Comment: I have same problem please tell me have you fixed it or not?