# HTML5 Audio duration is different in chrome and firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, firefox

I have read this question [HTML5 Audio Tag Showing Wrong Duration of MP3 in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20711488/html5-audio-tag-showing-wrong-duration-of-mp3-in-chrome) , but still can't solve my problem.
The audio file's link is here: 
http://img.kmf.com/toefl/listening/TPO/TPO-48-C1.mp3. In chrome, audio's duration return 168.408, but in firefox it returns 169.192194.

```js
document.getElementById('jp_audio_0').addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function() {
    console.log(this.duration);
});
```

```html
<audio id="jp_audio_0" preload="metadata" src="http://img.kmf.com/toefl/listening/TPO/TPO-48-C1.mp3"></audio>
```

Comment: According to ffmpeg chrome is right...

Comment: @Kaiido But how to solve this problem?

Comment: Ah no sorry actually FF is right ;-) Will add an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Chrome trusts the metadata (ID3 tags) that are in your file (almost everybody, even ffmpeg, does), but Firefox doesn't.

Your song is actually 02:49.17 but its metadata says otherwise.

When you remove these metadata info (I used this [online tool](http://www.watermark-images.com/mp3-tag-editor-online.aspx)), then everyone agrees that your audio has a duration of 02:49.17 (or 169.16898s for chrome and 169.192194 for FF).

Here is the file, without metadata :

```js
a.onloadedmetadata = e => console.log(a.duration);
```

```html
<audio id="a" src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/adw96fb4xaz377n/TPO-48-C1_noID3.mp3" controls>
```

Comment: Chrome returns 169.16898 and FF returns 169.192194. Is this right?@Kaiido

Comment: ok, but even when data is scrubbed there is a diff in length, how to get it same?

Comment: Yes, a few ms of difference is _normal_/expected No real way to get exactly the same.

Comment: @Kaiido Thank you, I also have a question. Because there are many many mp3 files in my production environment, are there any methods can solve this problem quickly?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/441361/strip-metadata-from-all-formats-with-ffmpeg

Answer (score 1):

For anyone coming along later, I ran into the same issue. For whatever reason, Firefox doesn't report the `audio.duration` properly at the moment the `loadedmetadata` event is fired. At that point in time, the `audio.duration` will only be equal to whatever portion of audio has been buffered by the browser, which likely won't be the full duration of the entire audio clip. In contrast, Chrome correctly reports the full duration on `loadedmetadata`.

To get around this limitation on Firefox, I instead started listening to the [`durationchange` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/durationchange_event) which will fired whenever the browser buffers another chunk of the audio. Unfortunately this means that it usually takes a few events before the true (full) duration is given, so at first you'll get like `3.4567` (in secs) and then `24.456` and so on, but after a few updates, you'll get the true duration and then you'll stop receiving updates once the entire clip has been buffered.

This is clearly not ideal and probably won't suffice in all use cases, but the audio clips I was playing are fairly short so it's not a big deal if the duration changes a couple of times right as the audio starts playing. But there aren't a ton of other options in Firefox.